# Riemann–Hurwitz Formula for Normal Projective Curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, completion

My question refers to the proof of Theorem 7.4.16 from Liu's "Algebraic Geometry" at page 290 :

[image]

QUESTION: Why does $e'_x= length_{\hat{B}}(W_{\hat{B}/\hat{A}}/\hat{B})$ hold?

During the proof we define $e'_x$  as $e'_x := length_{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}}(\omega_f/ \mathcal{O}_X)_x +1$.

As the excerpt explains we obtain $(\omega_f/ \mathcal{O}_X)_x = Hom_{\hat{A}}(\hat{B},\hat{A})/\hat{B}$ and Exercise 6.4.8 provides the identification: $Hom_{\hat{A}}(\hat{B},\hat{A}) \cong W_{\hat{B}/\hat{A}}$, as see below:

[image]

Combine this both results we get:

$e'_x = length_{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}}(W_{\hat{B}/\hat{A}}/\hat{B}) +1$.

But how to concude the final step

$$length_{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}}(\omega_f/ \mathcal{O}_X)_x +1= length_{\hat{B}}(W_{\hat{B}/\hat{A}}/\hat{B})$$?

Especially what happens with the additional $+1$ on the left side?

Lemma 7.1.36(page 262) tells

[image]

but applying this to our situation (with $A=O_{X,x}, B=\hat{A}$) leeds to conclusion that the "+1" is wrong? Or where is the error in my reasonings?